# Android - Creating Views dynamically does not work as expected

Tags: java, android, json, view

I am developing an android application in which I am creating views like `RadioButton`,`CheckBox`,`EditText` dynamically based on `json` response and adding to `LinearLayout` using Java programmatically. 
In micromax A114 , I got the result as expected!
 [image: here] .

But when I tested with `Samsung note edge` it gets collapsed and does not looks well .

[image: here].

Here is the coding I used

```
for (int dynamicViews = 0; dynamicViews < FormFieldsController
                .initializeFormFieldsController().initializeFormFields().size(); dynamicViews++){


int fieldType = Integer.parseInt(formFields.getFieldType());
switch (fieldType) {
    case VIEW_TYPE_EDIT_TEXT:
                    LinearLayout fieldLabel = new LinearLayout(context);
                    fieldLabel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 40);
                    params.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);

                    TextView label = new TextView(context);
                    label.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.text_area_field_title_background));

                    label.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    label.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 0);
                    label.setText(formFields.getFieldName());
                    label.setLayoutParams(params);
                    fieldLabel.addView(label);

                    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);

                    final EditText editText = new EditText(context);
                    editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 10);
                    editText.setLayoutParams(params);
                    editText.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.cornerless_rc_bg));
                    editText.setHint("Type Here ...");

                    if (formFields.getCrfFormField().getFieldValue() != null) {
                        editText.setText(formFields.getCrfFormField()
                                .getFieldValue());
                    }
                    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            FormFieldsController.initializeFormFieldsController()
                                    .initializeFormFields().get(position)
                                    .getCrfFormField()
                                    .setFieldValue(editText.getText().toString());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int count, int after) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int before, int count) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                    fieldLabel.addView(editText);
                    container.addView(fieldLabel);

                    break;
}
}
```

Comment: The height of the View is fixed (40) but the pixel density isn't the same on all devices. Maybe you need to calculate the height dynamically based on screen density ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the height of your `View` like this :

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 40);
```

There's no doc on this constructor but javadoc for `LinearLayout.LayoutParams (int width, int height, float weight)` says the following :

> Parameters
>
> width the width, either MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT or a
>   fixed size in pixels
>
> height the height, either MATCH_PARENT,
>   WRAP_CONTENT or a fixed size in pixels

This essentially means that the constructor you are using is taking pixels, not dp. Since pixel density varies from one device to another, you need to calculate the height of your `View` in pixels at runtime based on screen density. You can use the following method to convert dp to pixels :

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int)((dp * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
}
```